# Retrieving referral url application

Tags: php

Let say we've the following

Objective : User will post certain exact URL `$refere` to lock viewing text content and only be allowed for view if the viwer is coming from the same exact URL `$refere`.

```
$refere = "http://www.site_site.com"; // User will post it
$r = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // To get real referral
```

and i want to do the following

```
<?PHP

if(stripos($r, $refere) == false){

echo "Wrong";

} else { ?>

echo "Go";

}

?>
```

It always gives me `$r = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` blank ! so does it deprecated on any PHP version 4 or 5 whatever !

Also

what is the user posted `$refere` like `https://` or missed `www.` or only posted `site_site.com` while the `$r = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` showing `www.site_site.com`

so can anyone help me to adjust this code to be working fine no matter the user posted the `$refere` link fully or only `site_site.com`.

Comment: I've used also $r = getenv("HTTP_REFERER"); echo $ref; and also blank !

Comment: Note that your comparison will fail if the HTTP referer starts with $refere, because that will make stripos return 0 as the position. In PHP, 0 == false, so use === false!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_SERVER['REFERER']` variable will only be set when you click a link to your page from another page and if the browser (or an eventual proxy or firewall you're on) isn't removing the referer header.

To your second question: do some string comparisons. The functions [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) will be of great help.

Comment: yes i did sure clicked on link from another website sending me to the page on another website that would Retrieving referral url but it is blank , is there any other way rather than $_SERVER['REFERER'] !

Comment: @JackBen in short: no, there isn't. If a var_dump($_SERVER) does not reveil a referrer, then the browser or a proxy or firewall must remove the header.

Comment: thanks that was right due to firewall and now it works fine however it still shows some error , it needs both $r and $refere to identical [ Example : let $refere = http://www.my_site.info and when i click on the link there then the $r = http://my_site.info/go.php , it gives me Wrong as it doesn't see both are the same ] !